# RSA key generation error using BouncyCastle API

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have a very simple and short program:-

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
RSAKeyPairGenerator kpg = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
kpg.init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

According to the BoucnyCastle API, I should get an RSA key pair as a result of this. Instead I am getting:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.KeyGenerationParameters cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyGenerationParameters
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.RSAKeyPairGenerator.init(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: The exception is thrown in the 'init' method.

Comment: `KeyGenerationParameters` should probably be an abstract class or an interface. Pretend it is, and supply an instance of `RSAKeyGenerationParameters` to the `kpg.init()` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the provider specific generator, so you must use the provider specific parameter classes as well. Alternatively use the JCE API in a provider independent manner:

```
KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
gen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair kp = gen.generateKeyPair();
```

This still uses BouncyCastle but all provider specific stuff is hidden behind the JCE API.